# how to cherry pick a patch with all its dependencies?

Tags: gerrit, cherry-pick, git-cherry-pick

I have seen these 2 posts:

1. https://code.google.com/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=1123
2. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/repo-discuss/qlP-Yxlxg68/yWJxZVR9mnQJ

Is it enabled or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the Rebase-if-necessary submit type was added in Gerrit 2.6.  For this to work the project owner/administrator must select this submit type for the project(s) wanting this feature.

From Projects->List, select the repository you wish to use this submit strategy. Change the Submit Type to 'Rebase if necessary' and save changes.

Comment: can you add some explanation of how to do it?

Comment: From Projects->List, select the repository you wish to use this submit strategy.  Change the Submit Type to 'Rebase if necessary' and save changes.  Making this change requires (I believe) project owner permissions.

Comment: please add it to your answer since I select it as the right one, may it be complete.